# Is the Microsoft Word IGNORE ALL command supposed to persist?

Tags: microsoft-word

My usual experience is that if I save a Word document to my computer and then close Word, any words that I previously marked as IGNORE ALL are not flagged as errors when I reopen the document.

**I have been unable to find a clear statement that this is the intent of the command. Is IGNORE ALL supposed/documented to persist?**

But it is also my experience that I save this same document to SharePoint and then reopen it, the previous IGNORE ALL commands don't seem to be respected.

**Can anyone explain the two different experiences?**

Finally, I'm not 100% sure that Word ALWAYS behaves the same way, but the behaviors described above certainly happen in almost all my tests.

Sadly, I'm still using Word 2010 in all environments.

Comment: I think this is expected behaviour in case the document has changed between opens. However I can't find any documentation for this.